# filter manytomanyfield form 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, manytomanyfield

I have theses classes in my **models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

class Address(models.Model)
    title = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    child = models.ManyToManyField(Child)
```

Because I wanted "child" field in "Address" model only displays "child" objects that are related to "parent" I wrote this code to my **forms.py**

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ('title', 'parent', 'child')

    def __init__(self, parent_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['child'].queryset = Child.objects.filter(parent__id=parent_id)
```

**views.py**

```
def address(request, parent_id):
    parent = get_object_or_404(Parent, id=parent_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddressForm(request.POST, parent_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = form.save(commit=False)
            address.parent = parent
            address.save()
            return redirect('app:address_added')
    else:
        form = AddressForm(parent_id)
    template = "add_address.html"
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The result : the child field displays only the child objects related to parent requested. which what I want.

The problem : when I submit I get this error :

> AttributeError at /manage/add_address/ 'str' object has no attribute
>   'get'
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/Developer/Desktop/Projects/******/***/views.py" in
>   add_address
>     167.         if form.is_valid():
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in is_valid
>     169.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in errors
>     161.             self.full_clean()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in full_clean
>     370.         self._clean_fields()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py"
>   in _clean_fields
>     382.                 value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(self.data, self.files,
>   self.add_prefix(name))
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py"
>   in value_from_datadict
>     427.         upload = super(ClearableFileInput, self).value_from_datadict(data, files, name)
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/widgets.py"
>   in value_from_datadict
>     354.         return files.get(name)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /manage/add_address/ Exception
>   Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Help please?

Comment: Can you get a stacktrace?

Comment: How do I get stacktrace?

Comment: I don't know Django and where it hides it. But one is thrown for sure.

Comment: post your full traceback.

Comment: sure you have posted teh complete form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made `parent_id` the first positional argument to the form, so you should pass it as such in the POST block:

```
form = AddressForm(parent_id, request.POST)
```

Note that it is better not to change the signature of the form at all, but use kwargs:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    parent_id = kwargs.pop('parent_id', None)
    super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and do:

```
form = AddressForm(request.POST, parent_id=parent_id)
```

in the POST block and

```
form = AddressForm(parent_id=parent_id)
```

in the else.

Comment: I don't get the error anymore. But, the selected 'child' in the form doesn't save!

Comment: been saved by adding form.save_m2m() to my view. thank you very much